# Installed new PHP version, not working

Tags: apt, php

I added a few new PHP version to my server according do this tutorial: https://www.23systems.net/2016/01/installing-php-5-6-x-7-0-x-ubuntu-14-04-virtualmin-5-0gpl-using-ppa/, by addding `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

However after `sudo aptitude install pkg-php-tools php5.6 php5.6-cgi php5.6-cli php5.6-dbg php5.6-common php5.6-curl php5.6-gd php5.6-imap php5.6-intl php5.6-mysql php5.6-pspell php5.6-sqlite3 php5.6-tidy php5.6-opcache php5.6-json php5.6-bz2 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-readline php5.6-xmlrpc php5.6-enchant php5.6-xsl php-all-dev php7.0 php7.0-cgi php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-dbg php7.0-curl php7.0-enchant php7.0-gd php7.0-imap php7.0-intl php7.0-ldap php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-readline php7.0-pspell php7.0-tidy php7.0-xmlrpc php7.0-xsl php7.0-json php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-bz2 libapache2-mod-php7.0`

The PHP versions throw the following errors:

```
root@xxx /projects/xxx/xxx-site # php5.6
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_gd2.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_gd2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

For all the enabled extensions. I checked the folder, and there are no `dll` files there at all. Just `so` files. How do I fix this? My old PHP version (5.5) still works, but 5.6, 7.0, 7.1 don't work..

Answer (score 1):

Did you modify you `php.ini` at any time?. DLL extensions are for Windows; is really strange a error like that.

First, if your intention is work/test with various PHP's version I think something like [phpbrew](http://phpbrew.github.io/phpbrew/) could fits better.

For you problem, search in the `php.ini` for the "Dynamic Extensions" sections.

For see what `php.ini` is using you could do:

```
$ php5.6 -i | grep -i 'configuration file'
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/php.ini
```

Then, in that file your dynamic extensions should be `.so` files, not `.dll`. Also you can try with different `php.ini` (I'm guessing could be more than one for the different versions) with the `-c` option:

```
$ php5.6 -c /etc/php/other/php.ini
```

If that works, maybe you could just replace the file :)

Comment: This is exactly how I downloaded it, apart from enabling certain extensions. However I did enable the extensions from the php.ini file, this was probably wrong. I know there's `php5enmod`, how do I use this form multiple php versions?

Comment: @Richard: I think there should be symbolic links under a `conf.d` directory for each version